# Proving Linear Independence of Set

Tags: linear-algebra

This seems like a simple question, but I was wondering if someone could help. I am asked to show that if $z > 1$ and $\{x_1, \ldots , x_z\} \subset\mathbb R^n$
is linearly independent, then $\{x_1, \ldots , x_{z−1}\}$ is linearly independent as well.

I know how to prove linear independence with numeric vectors, but how does one go about proving this without a defined set of vectors?

Comment: I believe that I will need to show a contrapositive where all vectors are linearly dependent, but how does one write this so that it proves independence?

Comment: This is a contrapositive proof, as you note. If the latter set is dependent, the first set is dependent. It's a one sentence proof once you write down the definition

Comment: What does $\;x_z-1\;$ mean when $\;x_z\in\Bbb R^n\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio It is signifying the value 1 less than $x_z$. {$x_1$,...,$x_z$} $\in$ $R^n$

Comment: @wq1234 : See my edits for proper MathJax usage.
$$
\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n\} 
$$
This is all between just one pair of dollar signs or double dollar signs. Just one pair.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you for the MathJax tips. Sorry, this is my first time using that typeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the smaller set is l.d. then there exists $\lambda_i\neq 0$ such that $$\lambda_1x_1+\cdots+\lambda_ix_i+\cdots+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1}=0.$$ That implies that there exists $\lambda_i\neq 0$ such that $$\lambda_1x_1+\cdots+\lambda_ix_i+\cdots+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1}+0\cdot x_n=0,$$ which implies that $\{x_1,...x_n\}$ is l.d.